# Recurring Event DispForm - Exceeds ListView Threshold

Tags: list-view-threshold, recurring-events, dispform

When I open recurring events (DispForm.aspx) I'm getting the pesky "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator". Calendar views with indexes work fine. There's over 20000 items in the list.

I understand the threshold mechanism, but I'm unsure why a recurring event is triggering the threshold error, specifically on the DispForm. The page doesn't have any lookups or additional webparts to anything.

Is there any way around this? Can you have more than "x" recurring event items in a given list or does the recurrence cause any query to that single item to trigger the threshold limit?

Comment: Just an update, I removed over 14000 items from the list and got it down to around 8k, which still exceeds the threshold but I figured it had been working up until recently so maybe... but nope. Still broken. I opened a support ticket as I believe this to be a bug and/or something changed in the behavior.

Comment: After waiting over 2 months for Microsoft to review this (and confirm the issue), they ended up saying that this cannot be fixed and the solution is to reduce the number of items in the list below 5000. Apparently they're focusing on the new UI for SharePoint and don't have time to support their actual product. Par for the course I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, but not a fix.

This is broken with threshold error:
https://DOMAIN.sharepoint.com/Lists/CALENDAR/DispForm.aspx?ID=1597.0.2021-06-11T08:30:00Z

This is ok and lets you edit the item:
https://DOMAIN.sharepoint.com/Lists/CALENDAR/DispForm.aspx?ID=1597

Removing the date from the URL paramenter allows you to view the item with the ID and re-set the recurrance if needed.